# My button won't activate after typing in, I can't figure out why

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onclicklistener

After I open my application, once a letter is typed into the the top box my button is supposed to activate. For some reason it does the opposite after I type in one letter it doesn't allow me to add, but once I remove anything from the box it allows me to add it.

I've attempted debugging and I receive no errors at all. Am I missing some code?

```
    final Button addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            TopGame topGame = new TopGame(dbHandler.getTopGameCount(), String.valueOf(gameTxt.getText()), String.valueOf(platformTxt.getText()), String.valueOf(releaseTxt.getText()), String.valueOf(priorityTxt.getText()));
            dbHandler.createGame(topGame);
            TopGames.add(topGame);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(gameTxt.getText()) + " has been added to your List!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });

    gameTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
            addBtn.setEnabled(String.valueOf(gameTxt.getText()).trim().isEmpty());

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are enabling the button when the text is empty. You need to change this line

```
        addBtn.setEnabled(String.valueOf(gameTxt.getText()).trim().isEmpty());
```

to

```
        addBtn.setEnabled(!String.valueOf(gameTxt.getText()).trim().isEmpty());
```

this.

Comment: That worked, amazing how one little character can make a difference to the whole thing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you could use KeyReleased event on the field and add a condition that enables the button when the `!yourField.getText().equals("")` otherwise it gets disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside onTextChanged()

```
if(gameTxt.getText()!=null&&!gameTxt.getText().isEmpty()){
  addBtn.setEnabled(true);
}
```